# How to create a background service to populate a list in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, web, service, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity created in my Application which has a RecyclerView that is populated ***once*** **since the activity is started**.

How I can create a background service that starts on the Activity creation and runs on the background and checks through a web process, **every** ***x* seconds/milliseconds** for any changes and repopulate the list in each case accordingly, without drain too much battery?

Every opinion is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Running a service to check for update of web service isn't very ideal for power consumption. Instead of checking for an update in every second, try building a push service like GCM so that it can let you know when to check for update.

Comment: Well the "updates" that I was talking about is just grabbing a json from php script that I've written. If the json is different from the first one then update is required. Is that possible through out GCM? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. IntentService with AlarmManager or JobScheduler
2. Worker from RxJava package

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any possible sample for each of the two choices to help me out?

Comment: 1. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279995/in-0-18-how-do-background-tasks-get-executed-on-a-scheduler